# How do I get the full content of a part of a wattpad story?

Tags: javascript, wattpad

Wattpad stories are organized into parts. Those parts are split up into pages that automatically load as you scroll down the chapter.

Currently, the API documentation does not state how you get the story parts content, only general information like votes and title.

By playing around with the console, I have managed to get it with

```
https://t.wattpad.com/213731429-54abfd3e5-2?token=exp=1473597386~acl=/213731429-*~hmac=24dafb89f7765782ccbcd9a2f9c6e329e9e11645ccd9fbe836afc66a72a9ae47
```

Where 213731429 is the part ID, -2 is the page number (0 to display full chapter), exp is some kind of timestamp and acl is the part ID repeated.

This request is what wattpad uses internally to fetch the chapters, but every few minutes the required hmac changes, and I cannot seem to find a pattern.

https://github.com/pippinlee/forkpad/blob/master/server.js

also has a function called getWattpad. It is supposed to grab the content of a wattpad story, but the API (https://www.wattpad.com/v4/parts/213731429/text) returns

```
{"error_code":1001,"error_type":"InvalidEndpoint","message":"API method not found"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do

```
https://www.wattpad.com/apiv2/storytext?id= [chapterID]
```

For example,

```
https://www.wattpad.com/apiv2/storytext?id=294837373
```

returns

```
<p data-p-id="13a9b81ba54a745aca391b5ffc877297"><i>Image:Early Hyperloop World Map Video: Hyperloop video</i></p>
[...]
```

You can get the chapterID either from the URL when navigated to the chapter or from

```
https://www.wattpad.com/story/"+bookID+"/parts 
.table-of-contents>li>a
```

Answer (score 0):

I am Matthew. I work on Wattpad's public API.

We are currently working on releasing a new set of story APIs to the public, which includes story text. It's not quite ready yet and will take sometime.  Please stay tuned.

Forkpad was an app created on private APIs that we created specifically for a hackathon Wattpad sponsored last year. It was ***known*** and ***expected*** that those APIs would ***not*** work after the hackathon. We've since deleted those APIs. The new public APIs we are working on will be more durable so don't worry.

Comment: Thank you, that is a very useful answer. Is it expected to come out this year or later?